# Firefox vs Chrome Date Difference with momentJS

Tags: javascript, datetime, browser

I have a function that gets the date in the DATETIME format:

> 2015-06-18 00:00:00

Doing `moment.utc("2015-06-18 00:00:00").toDate()` will display different results in Firefox and Chrome:

**Firefox**: Date 2015-06-18T00:00:00.000Z

**Chrome**: Thu Jun 18 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)

Also, using `new Date("2015-06-18 00:00:00")` will return `Invalid Date` in Firefox, but adding a "T" before the hours will fix that issue. But then if I do `new Date("2015-06-18T00:00:00")` will return:

**Firefox**: Date 2015-06-17T21:00:00.000Z

**Chrome**: Thu Jun 18 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)

It's driving me nuts.

1. How can I get both browsers to show the same hour?
2. How can I get Firefox to display the result in Chrome's format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using a dedicated date library is to obtain transparent cross-browser date features. However, as soon as you run [.toDate()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) you get back the native `Date` object. If you then convert it to string by using the builtin [Date.toString() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) you've finally dropped all the library goodies and got back to vanilla JavaScript.

Tips:

- Don't use strings expect for display purposes
- Use the [library features](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) to generate those strings

Answer (score -1):

try

```
new Date("2015-06-18T00:00:00").toString()
```

looks the same on both for me